# Let Glide load images to storage cache

Tags: android, android-glide

In my app I want to cache a lot of images before showing them. I don't want to store them in memory yet, just in storage cache.

I am now using `.preload()`:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(item.getBigImages().get(0).getUrl())
    .preload();
```

Comment: You should use `.skipMemoryCache(true)` if you don't want to store images in memory.

Comment: And consider looking at `setDiskCacheStrategy()` if you want to customize disk caching

Comment: If I use ```.skipMemoryCache(true)``` will it still save in the storage cache?

Comment: Yes it should. Have you tried?